# Подключение scss файла в react компонент

Tags: reactjs, scss, импорт

На проекте импортируется scss файл в компонент так:

```
import styles from './dashboard.scss?module'
```

Без постфикса "?module" тупо перестает работать этот компонет(ошибки при этом нет)
Что означает "?module" в импорте файла стилей?

Comment: что-то с кешированием мне кажется

Comment: У вас есть какой-то инструмент, который осуществляет препроцессинг и сборку. Скажем вебпак. 
И где-то в конфигурации этого инструмента написано: воспринимать файлы .scss как обычный scss. Воспринимать scss?module - как css-модуль. scss - и цсс модули - два принципиально разных подхода к написанию стилей проекта. Поподробнее почитать про цсс модули можно тут https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/